# Event click on cell of Extjs Calendar

Tags: extjs

I want to call a function when click a cell in Extjs calendar

http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/remote.html

(currently click cell in that calendar it call "Add Event" but i want to call other function instead of).

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the [Ext.ensible docs](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.ensible.cal.CalendarPanel) (under Ext > ensible) you'll see that you can define some event listeners on your CalendarPanel. You'll probably want to add a listener on the dayclick event which is fired when you click on a day in the calendar.

Comment: +1 And if you don't want to have the Add event popup to appear at all you'd better return false from the dayclick event handler..